# JOptionPane handling ok, cancel and x button

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

There is one problem I am facing with my JOptionPane
if I don't key in anything,no matter what I press(the ok,cancel or the x button(the top right button in the JOptionPane)), it will prompt me until the I key in a positive value. but I only want the prompt to happen when i pressed ok.

If I click on cancel or the x button(the top right button in the JOptionPane), it will close the JOptionPane

How can I do this?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class OptionPane {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        int value = 0;
        boolean isPositive = false , isNumeric = true;
        do {
            try {
                value = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "Enter value?", null));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("*** Please enter an integer ***");
                isNumeric = false;
            }

             if(isNumeric) {
                if(value <= 0) {
                    System.out.println("value cannot be 0 or negative");
                }

                else {
                    System.out.println("value is positive");
                    isPositive = true;
                }
            }
        }while(!isPositive);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to close the pupup once cancel or x button is pressed?

Comment: @Braj yes I want to close the pop up once cancel or x button is pressed . what I mean is the JoptionPane will keep popping out if I don't key in any values , click cancel,ok or the x button

Comment: so you mean pop-up until any positive value is entered no matter where ok, cancel and x button is clicked?

Comment: Have a read of the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object)), it clear states the return values

Comment: try my option and let me know whether are you looking for this or not?

Comment: `}while(!isPositive);`  Give the user a `JSpinner` to select a value.  Use a `SpinnerNumberModel` to construct it..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The basic approach for this can look like I've showed below:

**Updated after @MadProgrammer comment.**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class DemoJOption {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(new JFrame(), "Message", 
        "Title", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, 
        null, new Object[] {"Yes", "No"}, JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);

        if (n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            System.out.println("Yes");
        } else if (n == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
            System.out.println("No");
        } else if (n == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION) {
            System.out.println("Closed by hitting the cross");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `JOptionPane.showOptionPane` return `an integer indicating the option chosen by the user, or CLOSED_OPTION if the user closed the dialog`, which means that `n == 0` would be more accurate, as `JOptionPane.YES_OPTION` could be defined as anything...?

Comment: No, don't rely on the constants of JOptionPane, you don't know what values they are set to and they could change between implementations/versions of the JVM, that's the point. Instead, you should be using 0 or 1 which represents known index values of the options array...

Comment: But it does not matter, whether they change something in values of JOptionPane constants, if only I use JOptionPane constant for `Object initialValue` parameter in the `showOptionDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message, String title, int optionType, int messageType, Icon icon, Object[] options, Object initialValue)` method.

Comment: In this case, it does, because showOptionPane is returning the INDEX of the OPTION from the OPTIONS array, not one of the constants. This means, in this context, if the user selects "Yes" the return value is "0", if hey select "No", it will return "1". It is just a fluke that the constants happen to be the same and you shouldn't rely on this been the fact, but instead rely on what you know. The only constant you can rely on, in this example, is the CLOSE_OPTION, because the API explicitly says it returns it

Comment: Ok, but even if option indexes will switch or change and will be for YES=5, and for NO=2, than `if (n == JOption.OPTION)` statement will "decide", which option was chosen.

Comment: No it won't because the return will either be `0` or `1` so `n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION` will now be `n == 5`, which will ALWAYS be `false`...see...

Comment: Aaaah... Ok, I got it :) Everything because of "static" indexes of `Object[] options` and possible future changes in `JOptionPane.OPTION` constants. Ok, now I see :) Thank You for Your patience.

Comment: I was going to also suggest trying to switch the order of the options to something like `{"No", "Yes"}` as a demonstration ;)

Answer (score 1):

Simply move the code in `try` block and there is no need to use any flag just `break` the infinite loop once positive number is entered.

Sample code:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    int value = 0;
    while (true) {
        try {
            value = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter value?", null));

            if (value <= 0) {
                System.out.println("value cannot be 0 or negative");
            } else {
                System.out.println("value is positive");
                break;
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("*** Please enter an integer ***");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JoptionPane#showInputDialog returns user's input, or null meaning the user canceled the input.
```

So instead of directly parsing the return value. First check if it is null (User Cancelled) then do nothing if not null then parse for the integer value